# What is the inverse of dctmtx() in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

During the stage of compressing an image, the following code is used.

```
img = imread('frm001.png');
img=imresize(img,[256 256]);
ycbcr = rgb2ycbcr(img);
y = ycbcr(:,:,1);
proc = dctmtx(8);
```

After this stage, the regular process of quantization, zigzag ordering , RLE and huffman encoding continues.
While decompressing the code, what is the inverse function for dctmtx() used here?

Answer (score 1):

The DCT is calculated as:

```
B = D*A*D'
```

where A is the image to be transformed, and D is the result of `dctmtx()`. The inverse of this is just

```
A = D'*B*D
```